# What are the tools to plot cluster results?

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering

I am clustering based on my cosine similarity matrix. Now I want to plot/visualize my very large clusters. I am interested in using a tool that is better than sklearn.

Please recommend me.

Answer (score 1):

ELKI has some very nice cluster visualizations. You could also use tSNE or MDS.

But as you used cosine, I assume you have text data, and that is not easy to visualize. *You* probably *first* need to figure out how to visualize your *input* data, then you can think about adding cluster information to this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. I actually have a feature vectors `x = [0.7, 0.2, 0, 0.1]` like this. I use these feature vectors to calculate the cosine distance. Can I use these feature vectors directly to plot the graphs in ELKI tool?